# Calendar week number to date anomaly using strptime

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, strptime

```
import datetime
d1 = "2020-W53"
r1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1 + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")
d2 = "2021-W01"
r2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2 + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")
print(r1,'<-- does I found TIME TRAVEL -->',r2)
```

Both are returning the same value

```
2021-01-04 00:00:00
```

What I am doing wrong ?

I guess Week 53 2020 should return december 28, 2020

Answer (score 1):

The output is as expected if you assume [ISO week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Week 53 in 2020 is a "leap week"; its Monday and Thursday both fall in 2020 (Friday is 2021-01-01). Week 1 of 2021 then starts on January 4th.

```
import datetime

d1 = "2020-W53"
r1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1 + '-1', "%G-W%V-%u")

d2 = "2021-W01"
r2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2 + '-1', "%G-W%V-%u")

print(r1, r2)
# 2020-12-28 00:00:00 2021-01-04 00:00:00
```

See [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for formatting directives.

---

With the `%W` and `%w` parsing directives, 2020 would actually have a week zero;

```
d1 = "2020-W00"
r1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1 + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")
print(r1)
# 2019-12-30 00:00:00
```

although starting in 2019, the Thursday falls in 2020. Week numbers would then go up to 52 (2020-12-28) and start with week one in 2021 (2021-01-04).

Answer (score 0):

It should be `"2020-W52"`. The `-1` and `-%w` pattern tells the parser to pick the Monday in that week and Week 53's Monday's date falls in 2021.

```
import datetime
d1 = "2020-W53"
r1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1 + '-1', "%G-W%V-%u")
d2 = "2021-W01"
r2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2 + '-1', "%G-W%V-%u")
print(r1,'<-- does I found TIME TRAVEL -->',r2)
```

Output:

```
2020-12-28 00:00:00 <-- does I found TIME TRAVEL --> 2021-01-04 00:00:00
```

Comment: "*Week 53's Monday's date falls in 2021"* - that is not true if the ISO calendar is used. I think the point here is that with the `%W %w` parsing directives, the OP's year 2020 would have a week zero.